# How to parse real Time data as shown in figure

Tags: android, ios, cordova

can you suggest any method to parse this data ?Actually that exc is running in my desktop.
and i hitting to my PC(local host).It is real time data i need to show real time data.I think i need to implement socket programming?

[image]

Comment: could you please paste the data here, and don't force an possible answerer to download and rescale your image, that one can actually read whats in it?

Comment: sorry i am not able to copy data ..:(

Comment: then no one might be able to help out! also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you download this exc file.https://www.dropbox.com/s/uikj2oagbrx6gii/LexSrcPC.zip

Comment: sry, am on a linux box. Couln't do anything with an exe. Also don't expect that someone will execute this, as it *MAY* contain malicios content... Try to post examples of the output...

Comment: do you have any experience of socket programing. Actually i need some socket  programming plugin in android or IOS to get this output

Comment: in unix a socket isn't much more than a file where kind of a stream is written to. You could simply read this file... also have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html or this tut: http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/

Comment: But i need this for mobile domain .I am using phonegap. so i need plugin to get this data .That why i am frustrated from last few days

Comment: Then phoneGap is your real source of frustration :)

Comment: Yes that why sir i need help .There is no much help using google.

Comment: Without seen you can't see the data that why i say please run that exc file.

Comment: I'm trying... but I have no experience with such "layers" that suppose to work on Ios and Android. You cannot use native librarys, or anything framework dependent. Thats why I avoid such Layers, and am not possible to help any further

Comment: And I told you Exe files only suppose to work on WINDOWS machines. I'm simply not able to run it, without installing much more that I never ever am going to need after...